# Make Stripe service a dynamic payment service

Tags: android, stripe-payments, payment

I want to use Stripe's service in my Android app. In my app there will be some kind of a store with different sellers and not only one, similar to ebay.

I have 2 questions about this service:

1) Can I make Stripe's service as a dynamic? What I mean, is there a way to pass the payment from the customer to the seller? I didn't find such an option in their docs. I don't want the money to go through me. I want it to go directly from the customer to the seller. Is there a way to do it?

2) Is there a way to pass the payment to the seller without saving his bank account details? Some sort of an ID to pass the payment through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) to accept payments on behalf of others.

2) With Stripe Connect, each seller on your platform would have their own Stripe account (either a [standalone account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts) or a [managed one](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts)). Each Stripe account would have to be associated with a [bank account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-transfers) (or, in the US, a debit card) so that Stripe can send them their funds.